# bad enclosing method attribute for class

Tags: java, декомпиляция

Мне нужно исправить jar файл.
Я открыл его архиватором, разорхировал класс файл который мне нужен.
С помощью fernflower я его декомпилировал.
В этом классе были анонимные классы, они в jar имеют имя типа имя_класса$1(номер порядковый), но декомпилировались они и импортировались в виде

```
import имя_класса.1(номер порядковый);
```

Точки я заменил на доллары
затем я внес исправление и пытаюсь опять скомпилировать командой

```
java -cp имя_jar имя_класса(декомпилированного).java
```

Но выдает ошибку

```
CFG.java:93: error: cannot access CFG$1
import age.of.civilizations2.jakowski.lukasz.CFG$1;
                                            ^
  bad class file: AoC2.jar(age/of/civilizations2/jakowski/lukasz/CFG$1.class)
    bad enclosing method attribute for class CFG$1
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the cla
sspath.
```

Как я могу это исправить? Или предложите иные методы редактирования class файла, там не сложно, фактически просто очистить тело метода. Я помню android dex файлы можно было в smali декомпилировать.

Comment: а его никто и не должен редактировать. Вы должны править исходники....

Comment: Вот я исходники уже получил, а скомпилировать не могу.

Comment: Впрочем в конкретно данном случае я уже внес правки воспользовавшись дизассемблером байткода krakatau, но хотелось бы на будущее знать как с описанной проблемой выше справляться.